# How to migrate sql_context.registerDataFrameAsTable from spark 1.x to spark 2.x

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How to register a data frame as a table in PySpark/Spark 2.x? I am using the sql_context.registerDataFrameAsTable(input_df, input_tablename) method with Spark 1.x. Now, I have to migrate to Spark 2.x and want to use the spark session instead of the sql_context. However, this method does not exist anymore in the Spark context. What is the best approach to replace that function in Spark 2.x?

Comment: you should read https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use directly `Dataset`:

```
input_df.createTempView("input_table_name")
```

or

```
input_df.createOrReplaceTempView("input_table_name")
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. For completeness, I used dropTempView in Spark 2.x for dropTempTable from Spark 1.x.